# Location based android app

Tags: android, google-maps, location

this is more of a generic big picture question so hopefully I have a good title for it above.

I am a beginner android app developer learning as I go. One of the first apps I want to make revolves around locations. I understand that I can use intents to utilize all the power that google's map api already has so that I dont have to do the heavy lifting.

However, as far as the actual locations, is that something that I need to research and type them all into a database or is there some sort of data source that already exists that I can just point to?

For example, lets say my app finds all stores that sells Wii console games. I will be responsible for keeping up with whether the store actually continues selling the product but what I am hoping I dont have to do is list every location of that store.

So if Wal-mart sells the product and the user chooses, find stores near by, it should have wal-mart come up in a list. But there may be 100 wal-marts within a 100 mile radius of the user. DO I have to key in every one of those addresses or is there some way I can program it so that it just chooses "wal-mart" as a search criteria and then google map api does the work of finding all of the locations within that user's area?

Hopefully that question makes sense.

Thanks in advance for any replies or pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

[Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/) - this is what you need. With this API you can search places near (but you can set range) you. I got this API call from their [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search):

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&type=restaurant&name=cruise&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

It will return list of locations with their name and some other information.
But one thing ... you have to have your API key which is free to some point.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So if I already have the list of stores I want to use, just not all of the locations, I can plug them in somehow/somewhere?

Comment: If i understand correctly. If you have your own list of locations then you can just mix Google Places with your own in your application logic. Other way is to add your own places to Google Places: https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/add-place